# How to set the color of a link with another agent under condition

Tags: netlogo

I would like to change the color of the links that join one agent (reader's breed) to other readers that have a flag (`TM? = true`). The code is something like this:

```
breed [ readers reader ]
undirected-link-breed [ rris rri ]
readers-own [ TM? ]

to start-TM [ ?reader ]
  ask ?reader [
    if any? other readers with [ TM? = true ] [
      let other-TM-readers other readers with [ TM? = true ]
      ask my-rris with [other-TM-readers] [ set color red ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

which returns me an error in the line `ask my-rris with [other-TM-readers] [ set color red ]` because `with` is expecting true or false and not an agentset.
How could I select the `rri` links that connects current ?reader with the readers that have `TM? = true`?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
let other-TM-readers other readers with [ TM? = true ]
```

you tell NetLogo to assign the *agentset* of all the readers for which `TM` is true to the `other-TM-readers` variable. So when you then write:

```
ask my-rris with [other-TM-readers] [ set color red ]
```

you are passing the `other-TM-readers` *agentset* to `with`, just like NetLogo is saying in its error message.

This is easy to fix, but first, a comment: writing `= true` is almost always superfluous. Your `TM?` variable is already a boolean, so you can check for it directly by writing `with [ TM? ]` instead of `with [ TM? = true ]`.

Now, to fix the error, you can write:

```
let other-TM-readers other readers with [ TM? ]
ask other-TM-readers [
  ask rri-with myself [ set color red ]
]
```

or just:

```
ask other readers with [ TM? ] [
  ask rri-with myself [ set color red ]
]
```

You could also ask the links directly, and use the [`other-end`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other-end) primitive to check the color of the neighbors:

```
ask my-rris with [ [ TM? ] of other-end ] [ set color red ]
```

That last version is also safer than the previous versions, because it does not assume that there is a link between the caller and the other readers: it will only ask the links that are actually present. (The first two versions could check that `rri-with myself != nobody`, but that would be less elegant.)

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to ask is how to change the link color with the other reader. This answer would set the other end agent to red but the link would remain with the same color, isn't it?. How could I change the link color to red?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about changing the color of *the link* in your question. (It's in the title, I should have payed more attention!) I edited the answer for a quick fix, but there is an even better approach. I'll edit again in a few minutes.

Comment: Done. I also think I understand now the source of your original confusion: you mixed up `<breed>-with` and the `with` primitive. I admit it is indeed confusing sometimes.

Comment: thank you very much. This is the first time I am using link primitives and is a little tricky.

Comment: Yeah, the primitive names are not always super intuitive (I still have to look them up all the time) but it's a very powerful approach. And not just for network analysis oriented models: very often it allows you to write code that is much more general, elegant, and extensible.